# How can I check if an int(input()) is in the range of the length of a list?

Tags: python

In this problem there is a list and user input.

The user will input a number and I need to check if the user's input is within the range of the elements in the list.

I have tried using range() and len() but I don't think I am using them properly.

```py
NumberList = 1, 2, 3

UserInput = int(input("Which number?")

while UserInput != type(int) and #not in the range of the length of ItemList:
   UserInput = int(input("Invalid choice. Which number?")
   if UserInput == type(int) and #in range of the length of the ItemList:
      break

print(UserInput)
```

I expect it to check if the user's input is in the range of the length of the list.

Comment: How exactly did you try and what do you mean *"don't think"* - did it not work? Errors (give the traceback)? Unexpected outputs (give inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Provide a [mcve]. Also note you `NumberList` is a *tuple*, and unless there's a particular reason not to I'd recommend following [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: `UserInput != type(int)` is wrong in at least three ways. Break it down: this is an inequality test (`!=`) between `UserInput`, which has to be an int to even reach this line, and `type(int)`, which is the type of the `int` type. `int` is a type, so `type(int)` is `type`, and you're testing whether an integer is equal to `type`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if UserInput == type(int) and UserInput in range(len(NumberList)):
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am curious. There is a ( before the range method. Why is that?

Comment: Good catch. There shouldn't be! Removed.

Comment: Could you shed some light on why you think doing `UserInput == type(int)` in code is a good idea? Also `UserInput in range(len(NumberList))` would be better written as `0 <= UserInput <= len(NumberList)`

Comment: `UserInput in range(len(NumberList))` is arguably more comprehensible, but `0 <= UserInput <= len(NumberList)` would be more efficient.